# Python list of tuples

Tags: python

```
L1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] 
L2 = [('A', 10)], ('B', 20)]
```

Now from these two list how can i generate common elements

```
output_list = [('A', 10), ('B', 20), ('C', ''), ('D', '')]
```

How can i get output_list using L1 and L2?

I tried the following

```
  for i in L2:
    for j in L1:
       if i[0] == j:
           ouput_list.append(i)
       else:
           output_list.append((j, ''))
```

But i'm not getting the exact out which i want

Comment: what do you mean with `common elements`? Common in the sense of position, ASCII-number (i.e. ascending/descending sorting...)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`[(k, dict(L2).get(k, '')) for k in L1]`

You can pull the `dict(L2)` out of the list comprehension if you don't want to recalculate it each time (e.g., if L2 is large).

```
d = dict(L2)
[(k, d.get(k, '')) for k in L1]
```

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn, This is what i actually want

Answer (score 2):

In case you are sure the order of the lists is right and L2 is always shorter or same length:

```
from itertools import cycle
L2 + zip(L1[len(L2):], cycle(('',)))
```